# Are there other URL parameters when querying a Monero node's get_info method?

Tags: full-node

When querying a Monero node like this: http://node.supportxmr.com:18081/get_info

I get the info of the node, but are there other parameters besides "get_info"? Can I pass in other data? Is there a list of other URLs I can get to via the browser besides "get_info"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a list of other URLs I can get to via the browser besides "get_info"?

All the daemon RPC methods are documented [here](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html).

> I get the info of the node, but are there other parameters ... Can I pass in other data?

[get_info](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_info-not-json) has no input parameters.